# Problem implementing reciprocally nested structures in Julia

Tags: struct, types, nested, julia

I am trying to define two structs, Node and Edge.
A node contains an array of edges, while an edge contains the destination node and the probability of reaching that node. Because of how the rest of the problem is structured, I cannot avoid having the Edge object.

```
struct Node
edges::Vector{Edge}
end

struct Edge
    next::Node
    probability::Float64
end
```

Whenever I try to run the whole script i get "UndefVarError:Edge is not defined".

If i try to run only the edge part i get "UndefVarError:Node is not defined".

Is there a way (like in C) to pre-declare the structures, or to tell julia to process the two structures together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible yet, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/269.

You can define an in-between abstract type in such cases till the issue is resolved:

```
abstract type AbstractEdge end

struct Node{E<:AbstractEdge}
    edges::Vector{E}
end

struct Edge <: AbstractEdge
    next::Node{Edge}
    probability::Float64
end
```

Answer (score 5):

What about using abstract types:

```
abstract type AbstractEdge end;

struct Node{T <: AbstractEdge}
    edges::Vector{T}
end

struct Edge <: AbstractEdge
    next::Node{Edge}
    probability::Float64
end

Node() = Node{Edge}(Edge[])
```

If you do any graph computations consider using LightGraphs.jl it has weighted graphs that might suit your needs.

Comment: :) we have a duplicate recommendation.